# Do I need a VPN into my cloud network

Tags: vpn, amazon-vpc

Should I be using a VPN to access my network on the cloud?
Up until now I would just SSH into the server I need.
However now I want to isolate different parts of my network.

Is it standard practice to use a VPN to access the necessary part of my network? It is my understanding that SSH is secure but using SSH would complicate my network security rules because I would need to allow access from any IP on port 22.
-> But obviously configuring a VPN is a lot of added complexity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While SSH is considered safe, doing this does make a lot of sense. You probably don't want your backend servers (DB, Fileservers, CI/CD, etc.) to be publicly accessible anyway. So I assume you either already have a private network for your backend or will get one in the long run. Since at that point in time you will have servers that are only accessible via the private network, you would need some way to connect to those servers.

One way is to create a VPC, the other is to create an SSH bastion host that does nothing but run SSH. This bastion host, or jump server, would be publicly accessible but also connected to the private network. You can then use SSH forwarding to use this host to connect to all other hosts on the private network.

You can either use SSH tunneling, or SSH agent forwarding. [AWS have a blog post about this.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/securely-connect-to-linux-instances-running-in-a-private-amazon-vpc/) Here is the gist of it:

- `ssh –A user@<bastion-IP-address or DNS-entry>`
- Once connection to bastion host is complete you can connect to instances on the private network: `ssh user@<instance-IP-address or DNS-entry>`

This way all SSH private keys remain on your machine, you do not need to place them on the bastion host.